# Anonymous Function/Reference Error with Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function

I'm having difficulties getting my javascript code to work with my site built in Wordpress. I have a jsfiddle which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/sarahk3112/aw5xR/13/

This isn't styled exactly how I want it but shows the desired effect with the slide down/up and toggle between the "portfolio" and "about" links that have sub navigation. So it works perfectly here but when I implement the same exact code in my Wordpress page template it doesn't work. The Wordpress site is currently in maintenance mode since I need to fix this so I can't point you to a live link there unless absolutely necessary (it's a client site and they're not ready to go live yet).

Here is the error that Safari shows when I click "portfolio":

> (anonymous function) - moderndayfloral.com

The error Chrome shows when I click "portfolio":

> Uncaught ReferenceError: slideonlyone is not defined

Here is the Javascript code in my functions.js file:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('span[class|="subnav"]').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        $(this).hide(200);
    }
    else {
        $(this).show(200);
        }
    }
    else {
    $(this).hide(200);
    }
    });
    }
    });
```

And here is the html code in my page template file:

```
    <ul id="hometopnav">
    <li><a id="portfolio" href="javascript:slideonlyone('portfolio');" >portfolio</a>
    <span id="portfolio" style="display: none;" class="subnav">     
    <img src="http://moderndayfloral.com/wp-content/themes/moderndayfloral/_/images/whitearrow.png">
    <a href="/weddings">weddings</a>
    <a href="/events">events</a>
    </span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/eventdesign">event design</a></li>    
    <li><a href="/boutique">boutique</a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="javascript:slideonlyone('about');" >about</a>
    <span id="about" style="display: none;" class="subnav">     
    <img src="http://moderndayfloral.com/wp-content/themes/moderndayfloral/_/images/whitearrow.png">
    <a href="/philosophy">philosophy</a>
    <a href="/services">services</a>
    <a href="/jenn">jenn</a>
    </span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/thanks">thanks</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accolades">accolades</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I hope this is enough information to seek assistance. I'm caught between a rock and hard place with not being able to make it live so you can see. I know Javascript needs a little extra care when it comes to Wordpress so I appreciate any help that can be offered. If there is any other info I can provide to help, just let me know!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It sounds like a conflict between different jQuery versions been imported

Comment: I've deactivated all of the plugins (some are javascript/jquery based) and the code still doesn't work. Do you have any advice for figuring out what jquery is being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap a function on document ready, it doesn't have anything to execute as soon as the dom is loaded, and you are checking for wrong `display` as `show` transforms in `inline` display:

```
var jQuery = {};
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    jQuery('span').closest('.subnav').each(function(index) {
        if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            if (jQuery(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                jQuery(this).hide(200);
            } else {
                jQuery(this).show(200);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the wrap does not fix it and produces a new error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and then the uncaught reference error again.

Comment: Yes that works great, as does my jsfiddle link from above. It's when that same code is in the Wordpress page template that it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the new error message: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: But I don't have any `$` in my code, your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The line number the error references is this line of code:     $('span').closest('.subnav').each(function(index) {

Comment: Pardon me. Your jsfiddle code was producing that error. Your code directly above produces this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" and then this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: slideonlyone is not defined"

Comment: Ok I temporarily deactivated maintenance mode. Here is the site: http://moderndayfloral.com/ Thank you for your efforts with this.

Comment: you didn't update anything in `wp-content/themes/moderndayfloral/_/js/functions.js`

Comment: Sorry I put it back to try another fix. You can reload and it will show your code from above.

Comment: please remake that file, you have some weird characters there `â€‹`, remake that file with only the function above.

Comment: You didn't remade the file. [Check this](http://moderndayfloral.com/wp-content/themes/moderndayfloral/_/js/functions.js). Please delete the file and create a new one.

Comment: I believe the person above may be on to something about different versions of jQuery loading or at least some type of conflict. Do you see this at all?

Comment: I do not understand from where that `â€‹` comes ... use this file: [functions.js](http://www.filehost.ro/download/28858229/functions.js)

Comment: I don't either seeing as I opened a completely new document and pasted only your code :/ I'm having trouble downloading your file. It opens in a window with words in another language...and does not download. Unfortunately, I must sleep so any further help will be addressed tomorrow and I will now put the site back in maintenance mode. Thank you for all of your time this evening.

Comment: Try again to copy paste the code above. It seems to have a unicode character.

Comment: Ahhhh!!!! You're my hero!!!! No idea why it didn't work before but now IT DOES!! and I added the toggle feature back in so all is well! THANK YOU!! :)

Comment: Brief pause on the enthusiasm...now my Photospace plugin isn't working properly. It worked perfectly before the new functions.js code. You can see this plugin on this page http://moderndayfloral.com/eventdesign/ Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the Carousel Gallery plugin isn't working now after the change with functions.js Too many gallery plugins on this site...

Comment: I think you just need to change `jQuery`, I've updated the code again.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't fix the gallery image and the navigation is broke again...